# Find association between Issuer Name and domain name by ngram model

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, nltk

I am basically working on Information security problem. Every organization has domain Name that is registered by certification authority. Certificate have lots of information but basically i interested in two category ,issuer Name and Domain Name .Issuer  is the organization name that is issued certificate to Domain Name .So  issuer name can issue multiple certificate to organization with domain name.
I have CSV file that has Issuer Name and corresponding domain name in which they have issued certificate .I want to find association between Issuer name and domain in python. I am stuck how to start with these entities to find the assocation.Please guide me how should i take two entities and perform association. I have basic knowledge about ngrams .I have seen examples over text but here is CSV file and I have two columns that contains Issuer Name and Domain Name. I don't know how to start and tackle it.

Comment: Welcome. You should give a sample input and the expected output, and show what you tried so far, otherwise no one will be able to help

Comment: Like i have Issuer_org(GlobalSign nv-sa) ,It issued ssl cerifticate to organizations(incapsula.com,claremont.org....).If i provide Issuer_org(GlobalSign nv-sa) to my model then will show all organizations that has ssl certificate issued by Issuer_org(GlobalSign nv-sa).

Comment: I have CSV file that contains issuer_org and corresponding organization .I have read this csv file using panda and Nltk library is also ready .The need is now that how to use these two entities and find the association.

Comment: @NaveedJamil, your problem seems pretty simple for us, seasoned Python programmers. But your statement is asking us to teach you the basics of data mangling in Python :-( Please, provide us with a sample of the CSV you are trying to process and any code you already wrote and why that code did not work. This is the bare minimum for a good question here in StackOverflow.

Comment: @NaveedJamil, also, you wrote "I have seen examples over text" and "but here is CSV". Well, I bet those "examples over text" almost sure involved "CSV data"...